# Nuget packages won't install

Tags: visual-studio, nuget

Using Visual Studio 2017, I cloned a Git repo from visualstudio.com however things are janky. The nuget packages won't install. When I try to build, the output is 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 1 up-to-date, 0 skipped. What do I need to do to get working?

Comment: What error are you getting?  What makes you think something is wrong?  It sounds like the one package needed is already there.

Comment: It turns out, the problem was a Telerik library that Nuget couldn't find. I would have expected a better error output than what I received. I had to add Telerik's Nuget to my list of package sources in VIsual Studo in order to get past this.

Comment: According to the build log, you should clean your solution and build it, and you said the nuget packages won't install, which nuget package you are installed and what the error log when you install it? Otherwise, no one knows your issue and give you any support.